# JavaScript, Whats the difference between defining variables with $ and without?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Is there any difference between defining variables:

```
var p_tr1 = $('<tr> </tr>')
$p_tr = $('<tr></tr>')
```

i'm using netbeans, and variables have different highlighting. 
I looked through FF debugger and found that variables are equals

Comment: the `$` makes no difference. It's just part of the name. The lack of `var` in the second case does make a difference however. With `var` you are creating a variable in the current scope. Without you are going to walk up the scope chain and set which ever variable you find with the same name, or you'll create a new global variable (if no matching variable name is found).

Comment: Nothing! Generally `$` is used to indicate jQuery objects -- but you could use it whenever you want.

Comment: @MattBurland, I tip my hat at your speed.

Comment: @CaseyFalk: I've seen some people do that, but it doesn't seem to be a widespread thing. Most people don't use `$` in their javascript variables unless they are coming from php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` sign is just a symbol that can be used in variable names. Creating a variable `a = 1` is the exact same thing as creating a variable `$a = 1`, or another variable `a$ap = 1`. The only thing that changes is the name of the variable. You can type `a == a$ap` and it will output `true`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference whatsoever, historically it has been used to denote jQuery objects.

```
var $td = $('td') // common use case
```

If you use jQuery, it might be useful to know at any point if the variable you're working with is already wrapped or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, it's for code readability and easier understanding, because usually $prefix is used for a variable when you have a jQuery wrapped result.
So in case you select an element with id `mydiv`:

```
var $mydiv = $('#mydiv');
```

But if you would have it's non jQuery wrapped counterpart, you would do:

```
var mydiv = $('#mydiv')[0];
```

This way you know that with the 1st one you can use jQuery functions and with second one you can't.